# Chrome Task manager not coming to foreground

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

When I try to open the chrome task manager it opens up in a window but it doesn't come into foreground. I can see the preview of it ihrough the Windows Task bar but I am not able to access it. The issue seems to be similar to the one detailed in this question : http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/t1bWSHFhoH4 but as no solution was provided to it, I can't seem to fix the problem. I even reinstalled Chrome but it's still not working.

I am using Chrome 31.0 on Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After being frustrated by this for weeks, I figured out the problem and it seems like a bug on Chrome's side. Actually it was coming up in the foreground just not in the visible space of the primary monitor. I noticed that there was something going into the left side of the screen.

So, to correct the problem I connected an additional monitor and made it extend to the left side of the primary monitor and there it was. I repositioned it to the primary window and it comes up fine now. Though I still don't get how it ended up there in the first place and even after reinstalls why it wasn't adjusting it's position to the primary monitor.

Edit:
As kinokijuf commented a better way would be to use Alt-Space to move the screen back on to the main screen.

Comment: Or you could just alt-space it back without connecting additional displays…

Comment: Ah! Could have then just used move of the menu and keyboard keys to bring it on to the main display. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks @kinokijuf and erosenin.  Full steps are [alt-space], select move, then use the keyboard arrows to slide it back on screen.

Comment: Absolutely amazing that it's 3.5 years later and this is still a bug. Alt-Space->Maximize worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on what kinokijuf suggested:  I wasn't able to move the Chrome Task Manager using the Alt+Space technique.  However, I was able to maximize it using the Alt+Space Technique, and then I just snapped it back to it's former place and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that should work every time on Windows 7+ is to use <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to hook it to the left side of the screen. Intuitively, you would think that this wouldn't help, since it's  on a "different" screen, but this key combination forces Windows to check the displays and will put it on a real one.

Comment: For me `win`+`arrows` didn't work, so I assumed it was a different sort of problem, but `alt`+`space`+`maximize` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just helped a customer with this. For the keyboard challenged, you can right click Chrome task manager in task bar, select maximize, and then drag title bar to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you can do is alt+space. From there you can maximize the window and it will appear.

To not have it disappear again when minimized, grab it by the collar(the thing you select when moving a window around) and place it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't going to use a shortcut. I solved the problem with few clicks:

From the notification menu on the right bottom -> project -> duplicate -> select the chrome task manager window from taskbar -> then go back to notification menu -> project -> pc only.